# Blackscreen with only mouse pointer after switching to Ubuntu desktop from Kubuntu on 15.04

Tags: boot, kubuntu, 15.04

After upgrading to Kubuntu 15.04, I am having a lot of problems.
On reboot, it was stuck at Kubuntu logo (it keeps on glowing) but nothing happens.

On switching to Recovery mode, I was getting "Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: No such file or directory (g-io-error-quark, 1)".

From recovery mode, I have removed Kubuntu, KDE and switched back to Ubuntu by using following commands:

> sudo apt-get autoremove kubuntu-desktop
>   sudo apt-get autoremove kde
>   sudo apt-get clean
>   sudo apt-get autoclean
>   sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

On reboot, I am getting a black screen with a mouse cursor (after nearly 5 mins). It won't proceed further.

Please help me resolve this without re-installing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. There were 2 issues.

**1**. First Issue was with display-manager. Found the solution by searching in this forum. This was fixed by reinstalling ubuntu-desktop and unity.

> dpkg-reconfigure -a
>     dpkg --configure -a --force-all
>     apt-get install ppa-purge
>     apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
>     apt-get install --reinstall unity
>     reboot

After this I was getting login screen but it won't login, because of Display driver issues.

**2**. Second issue was with `libegl1-mesa-lts-utopic` - which is a left-over during upgrade for Utopic to Vivid.

This was identified from `Boot in Recovery mode> Clean Packages`
Following are the steps I have done to fix:

> apt-get autoremove libegl1-mesa-lts-utopic
>    apt-get update
>    apt-get upgrade
>    reboot
>    apt-get autoremove
>    dpkg --configure -a
>    apt-get clean
>    apt-get autoclean
>    apt-get autoremove